# does resampling change anything? R

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, r-caret, resampling

I am using the caret package and the"glm" method so as to predict wether an air conditioning machine is on/off using some factors.

When I use different ways of resampling, I get the same results (confusion matrix and its measures: accuracy, sensitivity...) why are they the same? Isn't there a diferent in the results when using cross-validation or bootstraping or nothing?? I must be doing something wrong. This is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123)
library(caret)
library(gbm)

month <- factor(c(rep("january",10),rep("february",10)
     ,rep("january",10),rep("february",10)
     ,rep("january",10),rep("february",10)))

day <- factor(c(rep("monday",20),rep("tuesday",20)
        ,rep("monday",10),rep("tuesday",10)))

hourDec <- runif(60)*10

onoff <- c(rep(c(0,1),10),rep(c(0,0,0,1,1),3),
       rep(c(1,1,0,0,1),2),rep(c(0,0,1,0,1),3))

df <- data.frame(onoff,month,day,hourDec)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=factor(df$onoff), p=0.7,list=F)
training <- df[inTrain,]
testing <- df[-inTrain,]

f.glm <- function(training, testing){
  resampling <- c("none"
               ,"repeatedcv"
               , "boot"
               , "boot632"
               , "cv"
               #, "LOOCV"
               , "LGOCV"
  )
  for (i in 1:length(resampling)) {
    cat("\n\n")
    cat("- Resampling method:", resampling[i], "+ glm")
    cat("\n\n")
    fitControl <- trainControl(method=resampling[i],number=5,repeats=10)
    modelFit <- train( factor(onoff) ~.,data=training, method="glm", trControl=fitControl)
    modelFit
    print(modelFit$finalModel)
    predictions <- predict(modelFit, newdata=testing)
    cm <- confusionMatrix(predictions,testing$onoff)
    print(cm$table)
    print(cm$overall)
    print(cm$byClass)
  }
}

f.glm(training,testing)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If I step through your code, the output from the `modelFit` line suggests that resampling is set to none `Resampling: None `. I am not familiar with the `caret` package, but this might be why the code isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: The main goal of using resampling in `train` is to tune the model's hyper-parameters. So, the resampling (e.g. 10-fold CV) is used to find the optimal hyper-parameters, and then the model (with the optimal hyper-parameters) is fit to the whole dataset. Since `glm` has no tuning hyper-parameters, the resulting model is the same in all cases. If you want to see a difference in the results, try using a model with tuning hyper-parameters (e.g. SVM).